# Will I have to recheck my luggage flying YYZ-KBP-IKA?

Tags: luggage, layovers

I'm flying from Toronto (YYZ), Canada, to Kiev (KBP), Ukraine, to Tehran (IKA), Iran. Only one ticket is issued for the whole trip, and Ukranian International Airline is the carrier of both legs.

Can you please confirm that I don't need to recheck my luggage at KBP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only one who can kind of reliably confirm this is the airline. Contact them and ask your question.

Theoretically, you should be able to check through, but there may be some regulations concerning entering Iran.

Answer (score 0):

You should recheck with the airline, but usually, UIA flights through KBP do not require rechecking your baggage or even leaving the transfer area.

This KBP transfer info page may be useful to you: https://kbp.aero/en/pass/transfer/

Comment: By "recheck with the airline", do you mean "ask the airline again" or "recheck your bag"?